# How to assign a local mouse and keyboard to a seperate display accesible over VNC (ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, mouse, xorg, vnc

I want to turn a laptop, a Nexus 10, a mouse and a keyboard into two usable "computers". My current best plan is to create a separate display accessible over VNC for the Nexus to connect to in view only mode, and direct input from the external mouse and keyboard to only that display. I've seen guides for assigning different sets of input devices to different monitors, but I'm not sure how to adapt that to my case.

I've also considered attaching the mouse and keyboard directly to the Nexus. Unfortunately, none of the Android RDP clients I've found support meta key input from the keyboard, and none of the VNC clients support the mouse in any sane way.